# system missings when computing variable

Tags: variables, system, missing-data, spss

I'm trying to compute a new variable using 3 other variables. If all 3 conditions are positive, the new variable gives 1. My problem: if just 1 or 2 of these conditions are present, I get a value 0 when it needs to be a system missing.

Comment: Can you post your syntax so far and provide a little more context ?

Comment: I gave in this syntax: COMPUTE DD_new=E’sept_preTx < 10 & Eope’gem_preTx >= 15 & TRpieksnelheid_t1 > 2.8.
Now if one of these variables isn't a system missing, I get a value, while I only want a value when all 3 aren't a system missing.

Comment: That is how compute with booleans work in SPSS. Unless you initialize your variable with 0, the default is system missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get SPSS to calculate a value only when you have values in all three variables you can use this:

```
if nmiss(E’sept_preTx, Eope’gem_preTx, TRpieksnelheid_t1)=0
 DD_new=(E’sept_preTx < 10) & (Eope’gem_preTx >= 15) & (TRpieksnelheid_t1 > 2.8).
```

the `nmiss` counts the missing values, and the original calculation is carried out only if tere are none.

Comment: `COMPUTE` also results in user-missing if one (or more) of the variables involved is user-missing. The `IF` method always results in either 1, or system missing; never 0

Comment: It's bizarre, because when I use COMPUTE, I get 1 or 0 even when one (or more) of the variables is user-missing. Only when all 3 variables are missing, the new one is missing. Thank you!

Comment: Right I misunderstood the problem - see my corrected answer, should work better.